# prep.fuzzy error in R ade4 package

Tags: r

I am trying to use the prep.fuzzy function from the ade4 package to do fuzzy coding for two invertebrate traits (size and functional feeding group) to then create a distance matrix. I keep encountering the following error message:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
The fuzzy data set must be prepared with the function prep.fuzzy
```

Here is my code:

```
size <- prep.fuzzy(TraitsCC[,6:12], col.blocks=7, row.w = rep(1, nrow(TraitsCC)))
FeedGp <- prep.fuzzy(TraitsCC[,66:73], col.blocks=8, row.w = rep(1, nrow(TraitsCC)))

# Ok, now we use the variables to create the distance matrix!
ktab1 <- ktab.list.df(list(size, FeedGp))
distrait <- dist.ktab(ktab1, c("F", "F"), option = c("scaledBYrange"))
```

The error message is when I try to run the dist.ktab function on the last line. Any ideas about this error message would be helpful (the data IS fuzzy coded)!! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to reproduce your error with a data set available in ade4:

```
data(bsetal97)
size = prep.fuzzy(bsetal97$biol[,1:7], col.blocks=7)
FeedGp = prep.fuzzy(bsetal97$biol[,16:23], col.blocks=8)
ktab1 <- ktab.list.df(list(size, FeedGp))
distrait <- dist.ktab(ktab1, c("F", "F"), option = c("scaledBYrange"))
```

And it works... so I am not able to identify your problem. Please update ade4 and try again.

Cheers